# Modulus of z^-3?

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

What is the result of $|z^{-3}|$ and how can one show it?

I know $z = e^{i\omega T}=cos(\omega T) + i\sin(\omega T)$, but I cant go further...

I would be glad if someone can explain further.

Comment: In general, $|z^n| = |z|^n$ for any complex number $z$ and any integer $n$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams so is it "1" ?

Comment: If $z$ is on the unit circle, yes

Comment: @CameronWilliams I dont know if it is on the unit circle...

Comment: Well then it may not be $1$. Note that $4+0i$ is a complex number but its modulus is $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall Euler's formula:$$z=re^{i \theta}=r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)),$$
and recall de Moivre's theorem: 
$$z^n=r^n(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n = r^n(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))$$

Here, choose $n=-3$:

$$z^{-3}=r^{-3}((\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)))^{-3} = r^{-3}\cos(-3\theta)+ir^{-3}\sin(-3\theta)$$

We know that the modulo function is:

$$|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

So we simply plug in $a,b$:

$$ |z^{-3}|=\sqrt{(r^{-3}\cos(-3\theta))^2+(r^{-3}\sin(-3\theta))^2}$$
$$ |z^{-3}|=\sqrt{r^{-6}((\cos(-3\theta))^2+(\sin(-3\theta))^2})$$
$$ |z^{-3}|=\sqrt{r^{-6}\cdot1}$$
$$ |z^{-3}|=r^\frac{-6}{2}$$
$$ |z^{-3}|=r^{-3}$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. I'd advise you to commit those identities and theorems to memory; they are a cornerstone of complex analysis.

Answer (score 2):

If $z$ is a complex number, we can write it as $z = re^{i\theta}$; then $|z| = |r|\cdot|e^{i\theta}|$. By the comment above,
\begin{equation*}
  |z^n| = |z|^n = |r|^n |e^{i\theta}|^n.
\end{equation*}
Can you take it from there?